# Using a Variable Named "description" When Extending NSObject

Tags: subclass, ios8, nsobject

I have a project with a class that extends NSObject:

```
interface ExtendedObject : NSObject<MKAnnotation>

@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *address;
@property NSString *description;

@end
```

When I later use this class and attempt to assign a value to the object's `description` variable:

```
#import “ExtendedObject”

@implementation MyClass

-(void)viewDidLoad {

    ExtendedObject *myObj = [ExtendedObject alloc];
    myObj.description = @“SOME TEXT HERE”;

}

@end
```

I get an error:
`-[ExtendedObject setDescription:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

From what I have gathered, this is occurring because `description` is the name of a method of `NSObject`.

This was not causing a crash until I started testing on iOS 8.

Is my understanding correct and is there a way to use a variable named `description` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a read-only `description` property in `NSObject`. Use a different name.

Comment: Most likely a different compiler. If you really want to use `description`, make sure to `@synthesize` your property in the implementation.

Comment: @LeoNatan No different compiler. In iOS 7 `debugDescription`, `hash`, `description`, and `superclass` were all methods on `NSObject` with internalized properties, now they are public, readonly properties. This seems to be breaking a lot of things in weird ways.

Comment: True. They did for Swift interop mainly. Thanks for point it out.